# How can I use several data fields drawn from curated data at once?

Tags: curated-data

How can I use `"MinTemperature"`, `"MaxTemperature"`, and `"Temperature"` properties of `WeatherData` for one or more cities in one line of code?

Comment: What's the point of one line of code? Do you intend anything more complex than, say, this variant of an example from the help page? `DateListPlot[WeatherData["KABQ", #, {2008, 3}], 
    Joined -> True] & /@ {"Pressure", "Temperature", 
   "WindSpeed"} // TableForm`

Comment: "one line of code" is overrated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
 2)[`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking 
the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system 
is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to 
accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, 
[`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: @Soum: take a look at `Map[]` in the help files.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you could build on.  It only shows min and max temperatures.  The `DateListPlot` function layout is fairly simple for easy editing.

```
londoncoordinates = CityData["London", "Coordinates"];
londonweatherstation = WeatherData[londoncoordinates, "NearestStation"];
sydneycoordinates = CityData["Sydney", "Coordinates"];
sydneyweatherstation = WeatherData[sydneycoordinates, "NearestStation"];

DateListPlot[{
  WeatherData[londonweatherstation, 
   "MaxTemperature", {{2011, 1, 2}, {2012, 1, 2}, "Day"}], 
  WeatherData[londonweatherstation, 
   "MinTemperature", {{2011, 1, 2}, {2012, 1, 2}, "Day"}],
  WeatherData[sydneyweatherstation, 
   "MaxTemperature", {{2011, 1, 2}, {2012, 1, 2}, "Day"}], 
  WeatherData[sydneyweatherstation, 
   "MinTemperature", {{2011, 1, 2}, {2012, 1, 2}, "Day"}]},
  Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Hue[0.9, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], 
   Hue[0.9, 0.6, 0.6], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}, 
 Filling -> {{1 -> {{2}, Lighter[Pink]}}, {3 -> {{4}, Green}}},
 AspectRatio -> 0.5, ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {{"Jan 2011", "Mar 2011", "May 2011", "Jul 2011", "Sep 2011", 
     "Nov 2011", "Jan 2012"}, Automatic}},
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort"},
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["\[Degree]C", Bold, Medium], Null}, {Null, 
    Null}}, RotateLabel -> False,
 PlotLabel -> Row[{Style["Sydney", 22, Bold, Green]
    , "                   ", 
    Style["London", 22, Bold, Lighter[Pink]]}]]
```

[image]